# Одновременный подсчет элементов и выборка максимального значения

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql

В БД (*MySQL*) есть таблица *tab* с внешним ключом *parent_id* и некоторым набором полей. Поле *order* отвечает за очередность вывода данных и содержит значения *1,2,3 и т.п.*

Для проверки валидности данных нужно сопоставить количество значений для с одинаковым *parent_id* и максимальное значение в поле *order*.

Текущее решение:

```
    SELECT l.parent_id, 
           l.m, 
           r.c 
      FROM (  SELECT parent_id
                     max(`order`) as m
                FROM tab
            GROUP BY parent_id ) AS l
INNER JOIN (  SELECT parent_id, 
                     count(*) AS c
                FROM tab
            GROUP BY parent_id ) AS r
         ON l.parent_id = r.parent_id
      WHERE l.m <> r.c;
```

Запрос - **рабочий**, но очень медленный.

Вопрос к SQL-оптимизаторам: как упростить и каково направление размышлений в процессе улучшения запроса?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слишком сложно. Если правильно понял, то:

```
select parent_id, count(*), max(`order`)
from tab
group by parent_id
having count(*)<>max(`order`)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f251e/2)

Comment: Да. Это я, видимо, перетрудился. Пока ехал домой допер, что достаточно простого запроса... Блин, прям неловко за нагороженный огород. :((

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, давно хотел узнать, а такой вариант (агрегация в select\`е + повторная агрегация в having\`е) каким-либо образом влияет на скорость?

Я в таких случаях в select\`e даю имя агрегации и уже его использую в having\`e

Comment: @BOPOH, я думаю, что это не важно, максимум тут считается один раз. но не проверял, да.

Comment: Максимум по индексу практически бесплатная операция (достаточно получить самый правый лист в дереве), а вот с агрегированием непонятки... Агрегация + группировка без индекса - использование рассчитанных значений немного быстрее (стабильно 2 секунды против 3), но стоит добавить индекс на группировку - времена выравниваются.

Группировку глупо делать без индекса, поэтому может и правда не важно...

Comment: HAVING вот чего мне порой не хватало =\

Comment: а если первый count положить в поле, а having по нему сравнивать не лучше будет?
типа 
select parent_id, count(*) as _cnt, max(`order`) as _max
from tab
group by parent_id
having _cnt<>_max

Comment: @dimka3210, то же самое спрашивал @BOPOH. Никакой разницы не будет. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bc9d1/3 Думаю, если посмотреть исходники, то окажется, что выражение для having вычисляются для каждой группы, при этом если в select указано такое же выражение, то оно берется и так, без дополнительных пересчетов.

Comment: @dimka3210 `HAVING <условия> аналогичен WHERE <условия> за исключением того, что строки отбираются не по значениям столбцов, а строятся из значений столбцов, указанных в GROUP BY, и значений агрегатных функций, вычисленных для каждой группы, образованной GROUP BY.
Необходимо, чтобы в SELECT были заданы только требуемые в выходном потоке столбцы, перечисленные в GROUP BY и/или агрегированные значения. Распространённая ошибка — указание в SELECT столбца, пропущенного в GROUP BY.` (википедия)